# How can I write this so it's easier to understand?

Tags: ruby

Is there and way to write code like this in a way that makes what it does clearer?

```
a = (a.split(" ")[1..-1]).join(" ")
```

That deletes the first word of a sentence but the code doesn't look expressive at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
irb(main):024:0> "this is a test".split.drop(1) * " "
=> "is a test"
```

---

*Edited to add:*

> Explanation:
>
> - By default `#split` delimits on whitespace.
> - `#drop(1)` gets rid of the first entry.
> - `* " "` does the same as `#join(" ")`.

Comment: #drop, that's it :)  I really need to start working in 1.9.1 more.

Comment: It's in 1.8.7 too (just tested that).

Answer (score 5):

**code**

```
a = a.split[1..-1] * " "
```

---

**explanation**

`String#split`'s default parameter is " "

`Array * String` is an alias for `Array.join(String)`

On second thought, I'm not sure if it's *more transparent* to someone who is not familiar with ruby, per se.  But anyone who has worked with Ruby strings for a little bit will understand what's going on.  And it's a lot more clean than the original version.

---

## UPDATE

As per [**just-my-correct-opinion**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123357/how-can-i-write-this-so-its-easier-to-understand/3123396#3123396)'s answer (which you all should vote up instead of mine), if you are running Ruby 1.9.1 (which you should be, anyway) or Ruby 1.8.7, you can do:

```
a = a.split.drop(1) * " "
```

Comment: Don't cut yourself too short here.  The only reason I know about `#drop` and `#drop_while` is because I've used them in Erlang and Haskell.  Before I started with those, I used slices too.

Answer (score 5):

for somebody who is used to reading rexep this is pretty clean:

```
a = a.sub(/^\S+\s/, "")
```

ymmv

Answer (score 3):

maybe making the process explicit will help

```
words = a.split
words.pop
a = words.join " "
```

Comment: A good answer, but it removes the first element, not the last. Use shift instead of pop. (regex answer is still the best)

Answer (score 2):

And if you were using this throughout some code you might want to create the
methods in String and Array to make your code readable. (works in 1.8.6 too)

```
class String
  def words
    split
  end
end

class Array
  def but_first
    self[1..-1]
  end
  def to_sentence
    join(' ')
  end
end

str = "And, this is a sentence"

puts str.words.but_first.to_sentence
```

Comment: I was paging down through the answers thinking of posting just this!

Answer (score 1):

Something like following

```
a = a[a.index(' '), a.length-(a.index(' ')+1)]
```

No check though

Comment: You could be using `..`'s instead of `,`, and -1 instead of your last index, perhaps?